# Mongoid has_many relation returning no values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Suppose an app where users can give gifts to other users. There are two relations between the gift and the user (one as sender and the other one as receiver).

The receiver part seems to not be working according to the following code, where a gift is created but not retrieved when calling the association:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongoid'

Mongoid.load!("./config/mongoid.yml")

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :gifts
  has_many :gifts_sent, class_name: "Gift", as: :sender
end

class Gift
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user,   inverse_of: :gifts
  belongs_to :sender, inverse_of: :gifts_sent, class_name: "User"
end

alice = User.create!
bob   = User.create!
gift  = Gift.create! sender: alice, user: bob

puts Gift.where(sender_id: alice.id).count # => 1 (nice)
puts alice.gifts_sent.count                # => 0 (not so nice)
```

How should the association be defined to make the last line output 1?

Comment: You sould set gifts_sent as attr_accessible, create method uses mass-assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to include the inverse relation in the User model as well:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :gifts,      inverse_of: :user
  has_many :gifts_sent, inverse_of: :sender, class_name: "Gift"
end

class Gift
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user,   inverse_of: :gifts
  belongs_to :sender, inverse_of: :gifts_sent, class_name: "User"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a **inverse_of** to has_many gifts relation.
And to work the second relation named gifts_sent, You have to mention the **foreign_key** while defining relation.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :gifts, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :gifts_sent, :foreign_key => :assign_whatever_field, class_name: "Gift", inverse_of: :sender, 
end
```

And the gift Model will be

```
class Gift
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user,   inverse_of: :gifts
  belongs_to :sender,:foreign_key => :assign_whatever_field, inverse_of: :gifts_sent, class_name: "User"
end
```